# Kafka with JMX helm chart not working with Istio

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx, istio

I have a kafka with jmx helm chart. 
https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/kafka

I am able to deploy it on k8s namespace without istio injection enabled.

However if I try to deploy the same in a k8s namespace with istio injection enabled, the kafka pod is not able to come up.
It goes in Init:CrashLoopBackOff/CrashLoopBackOff status.

From documentation what I understand is the above kafka with jmx helm chart is starting a jmx sidecar in kafka pod for exporting jmx metrics.

Has anyone been able to get kafka with jmx up and running in istio enabled namespace?
End goal is the JMX metrics exposed by kafka should be scrapable by Prometheus.

Adding events section from kubectl describe pod $kafka_pod_name as requested by Nick:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age               From                           Message
  ----     ------     ----              ----                           -------
  Normal   Scheduled  3m                default-scheduler              Successfully assigned my-poc/kafka-jmx4-kafka-0 to my-kube-test-node-1
  Normal   Pulled     1m (x5 over 3m)   kubelet, my-kube-test-node-1  Container image "ibmcom/istio-proxy_init:1.0.0" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    1m (x5 over 3m)   kubelet, my-kube-test-node-1  Created container
  Normal   Started    1m (x5 over 3m)   kubelet, my-kube-test-node-1  Started container
  Warning  BackOff    1m (x10 over 3m)  kubelet, my-kube-test-node-1  Back-off restarting failed container
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide logs from pod:
`kubectl describe pod $kafka_pod_name ` and provide the Event section where described what happen with this pod

Comment: @NickRak I have updated the question with requested information, thanks

Comment: Looks like you have not enough nodes for cluster or you have pod affinity which restrict you to spawn that pod `Container image "ibmcom/istio-proxy_init:1.0.0" already present on machine`